# Daisetsuzan Grand Traverse in Hokkaido

Tags: japan, solo-travel, trekking, hokkaido

I have some doubts about the Traverse way:

- If I go at the end of April, what type of boots do I need? Is it snowy? How is the ground? How many km in 1 hour could you do if you walk fast?
- Do you know where could I buy the maps of the route? Maybe in Sapporo? And where can I buy gas or fuel? Does anybody know some sport or adventure shop in Sapporo or another town in the route?
- Anybody have the GPS coordinates of the route?
- The total km of the route are 55km? Where you finish, is it possible to take the bus return for Sapporo?
- Is it easy to get lost? or the way to follow is easy?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You have asked many many questions here.  Can you narrow it down to one specific question? Feel free to ask multiple questions if you wish, but one question per post please.

Comment: Don't know if you're still looking for a GPX file, but I recently created one following the "Hiking in japan" book and using the UUD cards, you can donwload it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3M3QULFICJwdmdZR3JoRlotTEk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Most of these are answered in the [Daisetsuzan Guide](http://www.idioimagers.org/Daisetsuzan-guide.htm) and [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Daisetsuzan_National_Park).  Briefly:

- April is too early, there will be snow on the ground and average temps are below zero.  Most facilities are closed or unmanned until June.
- The only English-language map I'm aware of is in Lonely Planet's [Hiking in Japan](http://shop.lonelyplanet.com/japan/hiking-in-japan-travel-guide-2/), and it's not very detailed.  Sapporo has lots of hiking equipment stores, [Shugakuso](http://www.shugakuso.com/) is well-regarded by serious hikers.
- [Everytrail](http://www.everytrail.com/destination/daisetsuzan-national-park/trips?page=4) has a selection of GPS tracks for the park.
- Yes, you can reach all main trailheads with buses, just check the schedules carefully.  [Basic guidance here](http://www.idioimagers.org/Daisetsuzan-guide.htm#getting).
- Depends entirely on the weather.  If it's a clear sunny day, no problem.  If it's foggy or a blizzard rolls in, big problem.  On average 5 people a year die in the park.